# Simple question about lattices in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: modular-forms, integer-lattices

Milne's [Modular Functions and Modular Forms](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF.pdf) states, at the bottom of page 10:

> We can normalize our lattices so they are of the form
>   $$\Lambda(\tau) := \mathbb{Z} \cdot 1 + \mathbb{Z} \cdot \tau$$
>   for some $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$.  Note that $\Lambda(\tau) = \Lambda(\tau')$ if
>   and only if there is a matrix 
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in {\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$$
>   such that
>   $$\tau' = \frac{a \tau + b}{c \tau + d}.$$

I can't make sense of this last sentence.  For instance, if we take the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in {\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$$
then we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \cdot i = \frac{i}{2 i + 1}
= \frac{i(2i - 1)}{(2i)^2 - 1^2} = \frac{-2 - i}{-5} = \frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5} i$$
and this is clearly not an element of $\Lambda(i) = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} i$.

Comment: What's your point? I don't see how anything you've written contradicts anything in the quote.

Comment: @anon: the point is that the statement is false if that equals sign is interpreted as being literally equal as subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "equals" should be replaced with "is homothetic to." The surrounding context makes it clear that Milne only wants to consider lattices up to homothety anyway, since those describe elliptic curves.

Comment: As best as I can gather from Google, "homothety" means multiplying the lattice by a nonzero scalar?  That seems like it would just rotate and scale the lattice.  I can't see how that takes $\Lambda(i)$, where there's a right angle between the two basis elements, to $\Lambda(\frac{2}{5} + \frac{1}{5}i)$, where the angle is not a right angle.  Am I just being stupid here?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: there is no intrinsic "angle" for a lattice, because any lattice has *lots* of bases. For $\mathbf Z + \mathbf Z{i}$, the usual basis $1$ and $i$ has a 90 degree angle, but there is also the basis $1+2i$ and $3+5i$, which does not. What a lattice knows are its actual elements, not any imaginary "lattice lines" that you draw to connect the lattice points together.

Comment: Ah, I see my problem: when I envisioned http://i.imgur.com/FuXxrwN.png, it seemed clear to me that you couldn't get any closer to 90 degrees than by taking http://i.imgur.com/BdGgRV9.png, whereas in reality you can take http://i.imgur.com/kIkoAYv.png.  Thanks!